# How to do role based authorization to static files in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

In an ASP.NET MVC5 and WebAPI2 hybrid app how can I do role based authorization to static files that are under /Scripts ?

Comment: One line question? Where is your contribution, what have you tried?

Comment: @JK I tried googling it furiously. I have nothing to add. I don't know what to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have your authentication and authorization setup, you can use the [following article](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/asp-net-mvc-routing-intercepting-file-requests-like-index-html-and-what-it-teaches-about-how-routing-works) to force the MVC runtime to route and serve those requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out if current user is in role by:

```
bool isAdmin = HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin");
```

If that's what you asked..

Then you can do

```
@if (isAdmin) {
   <li>Menu Item for Admin only</li>
}
```